# elseif not working in php as expected

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "test_db";


// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

//check radio button and update sql accordingly

if (isset($_GET['calc'])) {

$calc = $_GET['calc'];
}

if ($calc='average'){
$sql1 = "UPDATE `config` SET `calc_category`=1 WHERE 1";
$conn->query($sql1);
} elseif ($calc='high'){
$sql1 = "UPDATE `config` SET `calc_category`=2 WHERE 1";
$conn->query($sql1);
} else {
$sql1 = "UPDATE `config` SET `calc_category`=3 WHERE 1";
$conn->query($sql1);
}


?>
```

In the above code even if the $calc is equal to 'high' or something other than 'average', it still updates the database with 'calc_category'=1 which is only supposed to happen when first 'if' condition is true.

I have echoed the value of $calc and it changes based on which radio button is selected but I am not sure why always first 'if' condition code is getting executed.

I am new to PHP,SQL please help me where am I going wrong.

Comment: in the query where 1 means all rows will be updated.. check where clause and also use `==` (equal operator) instead of `=` (assignment operator)

Comment: `$calc='average'` is an assignment, not a test for equal to. `$calc=='average'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

double equal to needed...

```
 if ($calc=='average'){ /****// == instead of = //*****/
     $sql1 = "UPDATE `config` SET `calc_category`=1 WHERE 1";
     $conn->query($sql1);
 } elseif ($calc=='high'){ /****// == instead of = //***/
     $sql1 = "UPDATE `config` SET `calc_category`=2 WHERE 1";
     $conn->query($sql1);
 } else {
     $sql1 = "UPDATE `config` SET `calc_category`=3 WHERE 1";
     $conn->query($sql1);
 }
```

also check your query near Where clause.... it is where 1 ?????

Comment: Thanks I now feel that was a stupid question. Love how quickly you responded :)

Comment: Welcome... and I am happy that your problem is sorted out...

Comment: Also there is only one row in that column so maybe "where 1" doesnt matter. I actually copied it from phpmyadmin query so it exists.

Answer (score 1):

In your elseif statement you are setting `$calc = 'high'`.  That is not a comparison.  In order for you to evaluate if the terms are equal you need to use `==` or `===` depending on how strict you need the comparison to be.

```
if ($calc == 'average'){
$sql1 = "UPDATE `config` SET `calc_category`=1 WHERE 1";
$conn->query($sql1);
} elseif ($calc == 'high'){
$sql1 = "UPDATE `config` SET `calc_category`=2 WHERE 1";
$conn->query($sql1);
} else {
$sql1 = "UPDATE `config` SET `calc_category`=3 WHERE 1";
$conn->query($sql1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and detailed explanation, I couldnt upvote being a new user

Comment: No problem and no worries!

Answer (score 0):

for Comparison two values you must use '==' instead of '='.
appending value to a variable return true value so elseif section not work.
i hope it be useful.

false usage : if ($calc='average')
true useage : if ($calc == 'average')